# How to run/execute form in a PHP page loaded in another using Javascript .load() without refreshing the parent PHP page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Sorry for the very long title but it's exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a PHP page (let's call it the parent page) that loads another (the child page) in one div with the following code:

```
$("#compose_inputandoptions").load("compose_inputandoptions.php");
```

In the child page called "compose_inputandoptions.php" I have a form like this:

```
<?php>    
echo $_POST['option'];
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
    <input type="text" name="option" />
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
    </p>
</form>
```

How can I obtain a value for the $_POST['option'] in the child page
when I submit the form which is in the child page
without refreshing the parent page?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
>
> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

```
$('#compose_inputandoptions')
    .load('compose_inputandoptions.php',{
        option : 'foo'
    });
```

---

To submit the form and refresh the loaded child, do a `$.post()`. Without any other detail provided in the question, I'' attach the handler to the `document` of the parent and listen to forms in general.

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(){

    //reload child content
    $.post('compose_inputandoptions.php',{
        option : 'foo'
    },function(html){
        $('#compose_inputandoptions').html();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joseph but it reloads the child and the parent page…  
Is it because I put the $.post() method under the $(document).ready(function() of the parent page?

Comment: @Zorkzyd what do you mean by reload? on loading of the form? or when you submit the form? `.load()` loads via AJAX, no reloading happens.

Comment: I want to refresh the child page when I submit the form to have a value for the $_POST['option'] without reloading the parent page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just want to reload the child page when I submit a form in this child page, not for forms in general. The solution you give me seems to reload both pages…

Comment: Okay I got it ! Thank you for your help ! I have read more thoroughly the documentation to understand the process correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax POST submit to your compose page and load the result into the div:

```
$.post("compose_inputandoptions.php",
       {option : "something"},
       function(data) { $('#compose_inputandoptions').html(data);},
       "html");
```